# Hortonworks HA Namenodes gives an error "Operation category READ is not supported in state standby"

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

My hadoop cluster HA active namenode (host1) suddenly switch to standby namenode(host2). I could not found any error in hadoop logs (in any server) to identify the root cause.

After switching the Namenodes following error appeared in hdfs logs frequently and non of the application could read the HDFS files.

> 2014-07-17 01:58:53,381 WARN  namenode.FSNamesystem
>   (FSNamesystem.java:getCorruptFiles(6769)) - Get corrupt file blocks
>   returned error: Operation category READ is not supported in state
>   standby

Once I restart the new active node(host2), namenode is switching back to new standby node(host1). Then cluster is working as normal, users also can can retrieve the HDFS files.

I'm using Hortonworks 2.1.2.0 and HDFS version 2.4.0.2.1

**Edit:21st Jult 2014** 
Following logs were found in active namenode logs when active-standby namenode switch happen

> NT_SETTINGS-1675610.csv      dst=null        perm=null 2014-07-20
>   09:06:44,746 INFO  FSNamesystem.audit
>   (FSNamesystem.java:logAuditMessage(7755)) - allowed=true
>   ugi=storm (auth:SIMPLE) ip=/10.0.1.50   cmd=getfileinfo
>   src=/user/tungsten/staging/LEAPSET/PRODUCTS/PRODUCTS-138018
>   6.csv        dst=null        perm=null 2014-07-20 09:06:44,747 INFO  FSNamesystem.audit (FSNamesystem.java:logAuditMessage(7755)) -
>   allowed=true       ugi=storm (auth:SIMPLE) ip=/10.0.1.50
>   cmd=getfileinfo
>   src=/user/tungsten/staging/LEAPSET/MERCHANT_SETTINGS/MERCHA
>   NT_SETTINGS-1695794.csv      dst=null        perm=null 2014-07-20
>   09:06:44,747 INFO  FSNamesystem.audit
>   (FSNamesystem.java:logAuditMessage(7755)) - allowed=true
>   ugi=storm (auth:SIMPLE) ip=/10.0.1.50   cmd=getfileinfo
>   src=/user/tungsten/staging/LEAPSET/PRODUCTS/PRODUCTS-139954
>   1.csv        dst=null        perm=null 2014-07-20 09:06:44,748 INFO  namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:stopActiveServices(1095)) -
>   Stopping services started for active state 2014-07-20 09:06:44,750
>   INFO  namenode.FSEditLog (FSEditLog.java:endCurrentLogSegment(1153)) -
>   Ending log segment 842249 2014-07-20 09:06:44,752 INFO 
>   namenode.FSEditLog (FSEditLog.java:printStatistics(673)) - Number of
>   transactions: 2 Total time for transactions(ms): 0 Number of
>   transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 1 SyncTimes(ms):  4
>   35  2014-07-20 09:06:44,774 INFO  namenode.FSEditLog
>   (FSEditLog.java:printStatistics(673)) - Number of transactions: 2
>   Total time for transactions(ms): 0 Number of transactions batched in
>   Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 2 SyncTimes(ms):  24 37  2014-07-20
>   09:06:44,805 INFO  namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:run(4362))
>   - NameNodeEditLogRoller was interrupted, exiting 2014-07-20 09:06:44,824 INFO  namenode.FileJournalManager
>   (FileJournalManager.java:finalizeLogSegment(130)) - Finalizing edits
>   file
>   /ebs/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_inprogress_0000000000000842249
>   -> /ebs/hadoop/hdfs/name node/current/edits_0000000000000842249-0000000000000842250 2014-07-20
>   09:06:44,874 INFO  blockmanagement.CacheReplicationMonitor
>   (CacheReplicationMonitor.java:run(168)) - Shutting down
>   CacheReplicationMonitor 2014-07-20 09:06:44,876 INFO 
>   namenode.FSNamesystem (FSNamesystem.java:startStandbyServices(1136)) -
>   Starting services required for standby state 2014-07-20 09:06:44,927
>   INFO  ha.EditLogTailer (EditLogTailer.java:(117)) - Will roll
>   logs on active node at hadoop-client-us-west-1b/10.0.254.10:8020 every
>   120 seconds. 2014-07-20 09:06:44,929 INFO  ha.StandbyCheckpointer
>   (StandbyCheckpointer.java:start(129)) - Starting standby checkpoint
>   thread... Checkpointing active NN at
>   http:// hadoop-client-us-west-1b:50070 Serving checkpoints at
>   http:// hadoop-client-us-west-1a:50070 2014-07-20 09:06:44,930 INFO 
>   ipc.Server (Server.java:run(2027)) - IPC Server handler 3 on 8020,
>   call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.getFileInfo from
>   10.0.1.50:57297 Call#8431877 Retry#0: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException: Operation category READ is not
>   supported in state standby 2014-07-20 09:06:44,930 INFO  ipc.Server
>   (Server.java:run(2027)) - IPC Server handler 16 on 8020, call
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.getFileInfo from
>   10.0.1.50:57294 Call#130105071 Retry#0: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException: Operation category READ is not
>   supported in state standby 2014-07-20 09:06:44,940 INFO  ipc.Server
>   (Server.java:run(2027)) - IPC Server handler 14 on 8020, call
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.getFileInfo from
>   10.0.1.50:57294 Call#130105072 Retry#0: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException: Operation category READ is not
>   supported in state standby

**Edit:13th August 2014** 
We were able to found out root cause of namenode switching, namenode getting lots of file info requests and then namenode switching was happened.

But still could not get resolve **Operation category READ is not supported in state standby** error.

**Edit:7th December 2014** 
We were found that, as the **solution** application need to manually connect with current active namenode once previously active namenode failed. Traffic for namenodes in HA mode are not automatically directed to active node.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the way it was resolved is unlikely to help other users.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You need to update the client libraries. Use amabari to set up spark and have it install the client on the server. Then set your SPARK_HOME environment variable.